# Which highlight group is responsible for the confirmation dialog?

Tags: highlight, quit

If I have `set confirm`, Vim will show a confirmation dialog if I attempt to quit Vim when there are unsaved changes:

[image: Vim confirmation dialog]

Which highlight group is responsible for the colors of the text in the confirmation dialog? I would like to change the foreground color to dark blue instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some unknown reason it's `:h hl-MoreMsg`.

BTW. If you're unhappy with some colors it might be worth to give a try to a different color scheme, as there's a ton of them.

Comment: `MoreMsg` kind of makes sense, as it's an interactive prompt just as the MORE message is. I guess that the more message predated `confirm()`, so now it's misnamed.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Probably, yes. Though my first thought was "hl-Question" or such.